# How to understand that behavior of useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There is a custom hook:

```
function useMap(mapRef,  location) {
   const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

   useEffect(() => {
      if (mapRef.current !== null && map === null) {
         const instance = leaflet.createMap(mapRef, location)//упрощенный код 
         setMap(instance)
      }
   }, [map, location])

   return map;
}
```

This hook is called in a component that has props coming from the server.

```
function Map({ location }) {
   const mapRef = useRef(null)
   const map = useMap(mapRef, location)
   return (
      <div
         ref={mapRef}
         style={{ height: height }}
      />     
   )
}
```

My problem is that after the first render of the component, the setMap is called in useMap. The next renders of this component occur almost immediately (since the location comes from the server quickly). In the same hook, useMap Map remains `null`, and not what we passed in the previous render in setMap. After some time, the Map is still updated, but this can happen on 2nd, 3rd, and 4th renders.

There was an understanding in my head that setState, if it was called on the previous renderer, on the next renderer exactly takes the value passed to this setState.

I tried to check whole documentation of react.

Comment: have tried using uselayouteffect instead of useeffect, it feels like you want to trigger a synchronous re-render by updating the state.

Comment: also, setState is asynchronous, meaning that React batches state updates and applies them in a later time to improve performance. Therefore, you cannot assume that setState updates the state immediately and synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the re-render by using [the callback form of `setMap`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) which lets you provided value based on the previous value:

```js
function useMap(mapRef,  location) {
   const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

   useEffect(() => {
      setMap(existingMap => {
         if (mapRef.current !== null && existingMap === null) {
            return leaflet.createMap(mapRef, location);
         } else {
            return existingMap;
         }
      });
   }, [setMap, location])

   return map;
}
```